# Editing on index.php is not affecting the webpage in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am editing my theme in wordpress and added a new div with class named "sidebar"
but it is not updating on the website's homepage. The stylesheet is updating with the .sidebar class but not my index.php.
I have inspect the element by chrome's inspector and i can't see the div with class name sidebar.

But in the file it is there.
Is there any setting i have to do in wordpress?

Comment: is another page set from the admin side as home page ?

Comment: @Khushboo you mean a page named homepage or home? Yes

Comment: then, you need to add that div in page.php instead of index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add that `div` tag in `page.php` instead of `index.php`